# SignIn with Google on back4app + flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-server, back4app

I'm developing an App with FLutter + Parse Server (back4app), I crashed the part of making the login system through google, I'm using the following function:

````
Future<void> _signUpGoogle() async{
    loading = true;

    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn( scopes: ['email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'] );

    sigInGoogle() async {
      GoogleSignInAccount account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication = await account.authentication;
      final ParseResponse response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
          'google',
          google(_googleSignIn.currentUser.id,
              authentication.accessToken.toString(),
              authentication.idToken
          ));

      if(response.success){
        print(response.success);
      }else{
        print(google(_googleSignIn.currentUser.id,
            authentication.accessToken.toString(),
            authentication.idToken
        ));
      }
    }
    sigInGoogle();
  }

```[Google configs][1]

this is returning the following error to me:
````

╭-- Parse Response
I/flutter (28974): Class: _User
I/flutter (28974): Function: ParseApiRQ.loginWith
I/flutter (28974): Status Code: 101
I/flutter (28974): Type: ObjectNotFound
I/flutter (28974): Exception: Google auth is invalid for this user.

```
[Authorized domains][2]

Can anyone help me solve this error?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfJC1.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmrJp.png
```

Comment: What is the Parse Server version that you are running your app on?

Comment: i using on back4app Parse server 3.10.0 on flutter  parse_server_sdk: ^2.0.1

Comment: What is the server URL that you are using to initialize your SDK?

Comment: Please use `parse_server_sdk_flutter: ^2.0.1`
`parse_server_sdk` is now a general dart package. `parse_server_sdk_flutter` is specific for flutter and as a result easier to use.

Comment: I'm not using `loginWith`, but there has been a recent comment by Danaru87 that might help you.
https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/issues/506#issuecomment-726786699

Comment: @RobsonDona, did you already check this guide here from Back4App? https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/sign-in-with-google

Comment: @nataliec yes, i follow all this guide have.